# Why does dos2unix abort converting files with special characters by default?

Tags: text-processing, binary

The man page for `dos2unix` states:

```
Binary files are automatically skipped, unless conversion is forced.

...

-f, --force
    Force conversion of binary files.
```

If you run `dos2unix` without the `-f` flag on a file that contains a special symbol, for example vertical tab, it will fail with this message:

```
dos2unix: Binary symbol found at line 123
dos2unix: Skipping binary file foo.csv
```

My question is why does the default behavior of `dos2unix` assume that the user made a mistake if it encounters a file with a special symbol? Is it simply out of an abundance of caution that a user might run this on a true binary file and corrupt it?

Comment: I suspect *it's simply out of an abundance of caution that a user might run this on a true binary file and corrupt it*

Answer (score 1):

It does this because, while `dos2unix` KNOWS that the two characters `0x0d0a`, in a text file, are what DOS/Windows uses for End-of-Line, and should be replaced with `0x0a`, the Unix/Linux End-of-Line, it's not so clear for "binary" files.

A "binary" file could be an executable, an archive, a database, a data file from some unknown program, or compressed versions of the preceding. They might contain a pair of data bytes containing `0x0d0a`, or a `short int` with the decimal value `3338`, even a CPU instruction.

Simply replacing `0x0d0a` with `0x0a` in these files will break them (render them nonfunctional).

Since this is usually a Bad Idea, `dos2unix`, by default, doesn't do it.

But, since the Unix Way is to assume one knows what one is doing (shoot yourself in the foot if you want), and `dos2unix` isn't perfect at detecting "binary", there's an override in case of a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

*Why* would you run it on a binary file? To randomly hope that every `0x0d0a` should be `0x0a`? It's designed for ASCII text files; I'm not sure it even handles Unicode. As a safeguard, it stops you from corrupting a binary file.

Comment: The OP isn't running it on a binary file

Comment: @roaima - "If you run dos2unix without the -f flag on a file that contains a special symbol" implies they did. The answer still applies - it's a safeguard.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco in my case it was a CSV file with a vertical tab special symbol, not a true binary file.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen then you know it is supposed to be mostly text and it's acceptable. That's why they gave you the force option.